# StatelessKnowledgeSession and Drools Flow

Tags: java, workflow, thread-safety, drools, drools-flow

Is it possible to run a Drools Flow process from a `StatelessKnowledgeSession`? If so, how? It doesn't have the `startProcess(id, params)` method and seems to only implement rule functionality. I have a service whose method runs a process. So far, I've used one `StatefulKnowledgeSession` but I read that it's not thread-safe. One solution I came up with is to inject a knowledge base and create a new session for every call of this method, but that seems like a waste of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing the other answer,
you can use like this:

ksession.execute(CommandFactory.newStartProcess(theName, parameters));

Answer (score 1):

StatelessKnowledgeSession has a method execute(..) where you can pass a set of commands.  One of those could be a startProcess command.